# Mascara para campos Input HTML5

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-masked-input

Estou aplicando um recurso de adição de mascara em meu código, par quando o usuário preencher o telefone ou celular, a mascar ser preenchida automaticamente.
Porem, minha página não retorna nada enquanto usuário digita.

```
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- Tag das dimensões do bootstrap -->

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="icon" href="imagens/icon/favicon.png">

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#telefone').mask('(00) 0000-0000');
      });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="cadusuario">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <form action="cadastrarusuario.php" method="POST">
        <label>E-mail/Login</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail.." id="login" name="login"><br>
        <label>Nova Senha</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite sua nova senha.." id="senha" name="senha"><br>
        <label>Repita a Senha</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite sua nova senha.." id="senha2" name="senha2"><br>
        <label>Telefone</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefone" id="telefone" name="telefone" ><br>
        <label>Celular</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Celular" id="celular" name="celular" ><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-roxo">Cadastre-se</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: qual biblioteca usou?

Comment: Realmente não aderi nenhuma biblioteca, qual a melhor para execução deste código?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Plugin jquery.mask.min

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

 <label>Telefone</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefone" id="telefone" name="telefone" ><br>
 <label>Celular</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Celular" id="celular" name="celular" ><br>
        
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#telefone, #celular").mask("(00) 0000-0000");
    </script>
```

Se desejar configure separadamente o celular do fixo da forma que quiser agindo no script abaixo

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#telefone").mask("(00) 0000-0000");
    $("#celular").mask("(00) 0000-0000");
 </script>
```

**Máscara para telefones de 8 e 9 dígitos – jQuery**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>


<label for="txttelefone">Telefone</label>
<input type="tel" name="telefone" id="telefone" pattern="\([0-9]{2}\)[\s][0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4,5}" />
<script type="text/javascript">$("#telefone").mask("(00) 0000-00009");</script>
```

> O atributo pattern da tag input é responsável por validar o que está sendo digitado e o padrão deve sempre ser definido através de uma expressão regular.
>
> Na linha seguinte é apresentada a chamada em jQuery do .mask. O padrão utilizado permite a digitação de apenas números, sendo que os 0 são de digitação obrigatória e o 9 é opcional.
>
> Dessa forma o padrão de máscara pode ser utilizando tanto para telefones fixos com DDD e 8 dígitos quanto para celulares com DDD e 8 ou 9 dígitos.

[Fonte](https://www.codigofonte.com.br/codigos/mascara-para-telefones-de-8-e-9-digitos-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

Não está retornando nada pois tu não ta importando nenhuma biblioteca. Podes usar essa aqui:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.telefone').mask("(99) 99999-9999");
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="telefone" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, não sei como poderia funcionar da maneira que está usando.
Mas já usei essa lib e quando eu precisei usar fiz a seguinte abordagem:

```
 <input type="text" data-mask="(00) 00000-0000" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefone" id="telefone" name="telefone">
```

Adicionalmente não é mais necessário o seu código ajax com jquery, basta carregar a lib no header do seu html.

Não sei se é a mesma lib que usei, segue o link de referência:
https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

esse modo de uso está na documentação:
https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html

Answer (score -3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var check_phone = true;

    $('#phone').keyup(function(event) {

        var len = $(this).val().length;
        var val = $(this).val();

        console.log('Qtd of digits: '+ len);
        console.log($(this).val());

        if(len < 1){
            check_phone = true;
            console.log('Check phone reseted');
            $('#phone').unmask();
        }


        if(check_phone && len >= 3){ /* sometimes Chrome does not log keyup when typed too fast */

            check_phone = false;
        
            if($(this).val().substring(2,3) == 9){ /* mobile numbers in Brazil starts with 9 */

                $("#phone").mask("(00) 00009-0000"); /* either 8 or 9 digits phones */
                $(this).val(val);
                console.log('mobile');
                
            }
            else{
                $("#phone").mask("(00) 0000-0000");
                $(this).val(val);
                console.log('landline');
                
            }
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: This script supports mobile formats as (00) 12345-1234 and landline as (00) 1234-1234